# Strip file and write the chunks concurrently to server through TCP shows broken pipe error

Tags: go, tcp, concurrency

My client divides a file into multiple amount of chunks (128mb each), then it will upload the chunks to multiple servers concurrently using goroutines.

However, when I use more than 1 goroutine, I got an error from the my client program.

```
write tcp [::1]:49324->[::1]:2001: write: broken pipe
```

And in my server, the error is

```
EOF
```

Note that the broken pipe error and EOF error occurs in different chunks. For example, broken pipe error might happen when writing chunk 1 while EOF error might happen when server is receiving chunk 2.

Below is the client code:

```
//set maximum no. of goroutine running in the back
maxGoroutines := 3
guard := make(chan struct{}, maxGoroutines)

var sentByte int64

for i:= 0; i < chunkCount; i += 1{
    guard <- struct{}{} 

    go func(i int){
        index := i%len(serverList)
        vsConnection, _ := net.Dial("tcp", serverList[index])

        sentByte=0
        file, _ := os.Open(fileName)
        file.Seek(int64(i)*CHUNKSIZE,0) //CHUNKSIZE is 134217728
        for { 
            n, _ := file.Read(sendBuffer)

            n2, err2 := vsConnection.Write(sendBuffer[:n])
            if err2 != nil {
                fmt.Println("err2",err2,chunkName)              
            }
            if(n2!=65536){ //65536 is size of sendBuffer
                fmt.Println("n2",n2)
            }
            sentByte = sentByte+int64(n)
            if(sentByte == CHUNKSIZE){
                break;
            }
        }
        vsConnection.Close()
        file.Close()
        <-guard
    }(i)
}
```

Below is the server code:

```
func main() {
    mapping := cmap.New()
    server, error := net.Listen("tcp", ":2001")
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println("There was an error starting the server" +    error.Error())
        return
    }

    for {
        connection, error := server.Accept()
        if error != nil {
            fmt.Println("There was am error with the connection" + error.Error())
            return
        }
        //one goroutine per connection
        go ConnectionHandler(connection,mapping)
    }
}

func ConnectionHandler(connection net.Conn, mapping cmap.ConcurrentMap) {
    fmt.Println("Connected")
    //make a buffer to hold data        
    var bufferFile bytes.Buffer
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(&bufferFile)

    var receivedBytes int64
    receivedBytes=0
    for {

        if(CHUNKSIZE<=receivedBytes){
            break
        }
        n,err := io.CopyN(writer, connection, BUFFERSIZE)
        receivedBytes += n
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("err", err.Error(), fileName)
            break
        }
    }
    mapping.Set(fileName,bufferFile.Bytes())
    connection.Close()

}
```

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: It makes no sense to send things concurrently to a socket. What use is data that's randomly interleaved?

Comment: You are right, thanks for the reply. Just to confirm, I want to ask: so sending things concurrently to a socket means that data are properly gonna be interleaved. But if I send it using a different socket (same IP+port from server, different IP+port from client) then data will not be interleaved?

Comment: No, there is no way for the data to somehow cross between connections. Each TCP socket is a separate stream.

Comment: I see. I was just asking because I want to know what happens when there are concurrent upload from multiple clients. Thanks

Comment: I just checked that each time the goroutines connect to the server, it uses a new port, which means it is a different socket pair. Shouldn't it mean that data will not be randomly interleaved as they are in separate streams?

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct. The question sounded like it was about writing to a connection concurrently, but the code does have a single connection per goroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your client `sentByte` should be a local variable to the sender goroutine. Since you have declared it as a global, there is a race condition in your code. Try the below fix:

```
go func(i int){
    index := i%len(serverList)
    vsConnection, _ := net.Dial("tcp", serverList[index])

    sentByte := 0 // make sentByte a local variable, so each goroutine 
                  // has its own copy 
    file, _ := os.Open(fileName)
    file.Seek(int64(i)*CHUNKSIZE,0) //CHUNKSIZE is 134217728
    for { 
        n, _ := file.Read(sendBuffer)
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem.
But I have got another problem now. Although I can upload the files to the server without dropping any bytes, some bytes are incorrect (I checked the bytes using cmp and od). Would you know why?

Comment: I think that's because of your buffer size check in the client. There might be some edge condition that's maybe sending same bits of data twice.For example, the very last chunk of the file may not have enough bytes to fill up the chunk causing the condition `sentByte == CHUNKSIZE` to behave badly.

Comment: Thanks, actually I did check but I just didn't put that in the code snippet above. The loop for sending the chunk will break when there is a read error from reading the file (eg. EOF). So that shouldn't be the problem. The number of bytes of the file I received by downloading and assembling the chunks is the same as the file I uploaded, but the content is not.